# How to open %AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt on my Win 7 Pro?

Tags: sticky-notes

I want to open this file on my Windows 7 pro but the computer says it can't open it!  Why?  I'm looking for my Sticky Notes cause I need to find some lost sticky info.

Comment: See this...http://www.pcworld.com/article/191453/open_your_sticky_notes_file.html

Comment: related post...http://superuser.com/questions/44079/recover-a-closed-sticky-note-in-widows-7

Comment: Sorry, Moab but none of this helps. The PC article is not clear.

Comment: "The PC article is not clear" neither is your question

Answer (score 2):

You can use 7-Zip for extracting StickyNotes.snt file located @ %AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\ folder, then rename 0 file from each sub-folder of the extraction as .RTF. Hope it is needless to say what next :)

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Shared the simplest solution I used to retrieve %AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt contents, not sure what else is expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to open StickyNotes.snt file is with **Microsoft Word**. Just right click on the .snt file and then open with Microsoft Word. At the end of the Word Document you shall see your note.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open your Sticky Note file by double clicking on it because by default there is not a program associated to open .snt files.

Try opening it with Windows Notepad (or  another text editor of your choice, e.g. Notepad++);
Open Notepad then use the file menu (File > Open > browse to your .snt file)

OR

Open notepad then drag and drop the .snt file onto the notepad window.

Once it is open, use the Find function (Ctrl + F) to search for part of your missing note.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution on another website. 
Actually, there is a program to open sticky notes but the trick is that its not in the PROGRAMS folder. It is in WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 folder.

To restore your stick notes, go to
C:\Users\YOUR USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes
Right click your sticky note file (.snt) and chose OPEN WITH (select open if open-with is not there).
Click Browse button. 
Go to C:\Windows\system32 and search for StikyNot.exe
Done.

Comment: Can you link your resource, please? (Please **edit it into your answer**.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have it in the right folder? Check this folder:
C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes

Where YOURUSERNAME is your login user name.

If the file is present there by the name StickyNotes.cnt, and you start Windows Sticky Notes utility, it should open and show your notes.

You can also try the following Free program that shows the notes from the same file in a two-pane list:
http://helpingthings.com/index.php/list-windows-7-sticky-notes