# Can closed Sticky Notes be recovered on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, sticky-notes

The suggested answer from this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/44079/how-do-i-recover-a-closed-sticky-note-in-windows) does not work for me. While the file is present on my system, it has not been modified since I first started using this computer.

Answer (score 3):

Your sticky notes don't disappear when you close them.  Search for sticky notes using the search bar at the bottom of your screen.  Once the application opens and appears on the bottom bar, right click on the sticky Notes icon.  You will see 'All Notes'.  Choose 'All Notes' and your sticky notes return.